# How to use gdb to get ruby backtrace from different thread

Tags: ruby, gdb, ruby-thread

I have a ruby program that spawns two threads.  Rarely, it appears to be hanging on the main thread, and I'm trying to use gdb to figure out why.

Using the blog post [here](https://blog.newrelic.com/2013/04/29/debugging-stuck-ruby-processes-what-to-do-before-you-kill-9/), I have used gdb to attach to to the process, and call `rb_backtrace()` to get the backtrace.

Problem is, the backtrace is always from one of the spawned worker threads, not the main thread where I experience the hang.

**Is there a way to get a backtrace from a particular thread?**

I have tried using the gdb commands `info threads` and `thread 2` to change the active thread, but it has no effect.  I have also tried using a `ruby_eval` definition in gdb as described [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-gdb-to-inspect-a-running-ruby-process), but any time I try to evaluate a line of ruby code, I get the error `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`  Because I am working on an embedded system, I can't easily recompile ruby with gdb symbols.

Comment: "I get the error No symbol table is loaded" -- likely means you didn't invoke GDB correctly, or the binary is stripped.

Comment: It's an embedded system so the binary may be stripped.  I have tried invoking by `gdb /usr/bin/ruby -p XXX` or just `gdb -p XXX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rb_backtrace()` refers to a global `ruby_current_thread` variable that you can override:

```
# Make a note of the old thread pointer so you can put it back.
(gdb) p ruby_current_thread
$1 = (rb_thread_t *) 0x5619dfe485e0

(gdb) set ruby_current_thread = 0x5619efb7d3a0

(gdb) p ruby_current_thread
$2 = (rb_thread_t *) 0x5619efb7d3a0

# Write the backtrace to stderr
(gdb) call (void) rb_backtrace()
```

The ruby thread pointer (`0x5619efb7d3a0` above) can be found in the GDB backtrace of the native thread you're interested in, eg.

```
#7  0x00005619de86cf96 in vm_exec (th=th@entry=0x5619efb7d3a0) at vm.c:1693
```

Do set `ruby_current_thread` back to its original value before the letting the process resume.  Tested on Ruby 2.3.8.

Comment: Starting in version 2.5 this variable is called `ruby_current_execution_context_ptr` instead of ruby_current_thread